# New iTunes Connect - No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I have been thru all the posts on this one and nothing seems to help. No matter what changes I make or anything else I do, I am getting this:

[image: Xcode uploader rejection]

**Most of the (old) answers seem to revolve around 'changing the applications status to waiting for upload.' However in the new iTunes connect you cannot change the status manually as far as I can see.**

Things I have done:

- Verified the bundle id is correct.
- Surfed google and stackoverflow until I want to belt out a string of expletives so long that it would likely suck all the air from the current zip code that I am in thereby causing a natural disaster of epic proportions.
- Verified that my provisioning profile contains the bundle id.
- Verified and re-verified that everything seems correct.

I am using Xcode 6.3.1.

I know I am missing something somewhere. I have other apps on the appstore, so I am not a complete noob, but this is my first one under the new iTunes connect. I know I am missing something but I am tired of beating my head against this wall, so I was hoping the SO community could help.

Comment: I know that you should avoid asking something in an answer, but because this thread already exists in various forms on stackoverflow, I won't create it again. Still, after reading trough all of them, this problem still occurs to me. So did anyone followed all the steps here, and yet something NOT listed here solved that? I tried almost everything and I'm starting to go crazy since my App is working perfectly fine, but App Store Connect is refusing to accept it at all for days, and I really did nearly everything posted on that topic. So, if anyone could help me, that would be so so great. (Thin

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Seems like all I needed to do was to walk away. I hadn't received a response to the question yet, so I decided to refocus on the problem ... solved it within 30 seconds.

**Pros**

- I no longer want to punch kittens in the face ;)

**Cons**

- I deserve some flamage.

Answer (for me):

Basically, iTunes Connect (http://itunesconnect.apple.com) is the receiver of your App bundle when you use the Xcode Uploader utility (in Observer). So unless you have an App with the same bundle identifier created in the iTunes Connect web dashboard, you'll never be able to upload a build. Creating an App on the dashboard is easy, follow these steps from the iTunes home screen:

- Click the app in question.
- Click More ->
- Then About This App
- Then change the Bundle ID to the one you created in the provisioning portal.

Hope this helps someone ...

Comment: Thank you this has been driving me crazy! I forgot I made a new provisioning profile for the app and never changed it in this spot.

Comment: I spent an hour and half going in circles ... why couldn't the error message just provide more detail or at least a link to a Readme or something crap that was annoying.

Comment: It's been over two years since you answered this question but saved me from some head scratching. Thanks!

Comment: can not find these steps.could you help me out ?

Comment: For those still stuck after creating the Bundle ID. Don't forget to go to 'My Apps' to switch to the new Bundle ID before attempting to re-upload the archive.

Comment: I'd just add that the steps for a new app is to log into the app store connect and create a new app choosing wildcard and then copying the exact bundle id from xcode into the bundle id field. Once there is an app on the app store connect with the same bundle id xcode can distribute that app.

Comment: Since 2018, iTunes Connect has been rebranded to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/ (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346678/what-is-the-difference-between-app-store-connect-and-itunes-connect-app)

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem. I was logged in with an old user in Application Loader. What I did to solve it was:

1. Create an user in iTunes Connect.
2. Login in Application Loader with that user.

Then I could upload a new version of my application with any trouble.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Where is the application loader?

Comment: @RogerPerez, it is within your mac

Comment: May I know why a new user helps?  What is the issue with the old user?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.

Same message in AppCenter and instead Application Loader was failing with the following error: `No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'blah.blah.blah' is correct`

Solution:

Under `Distribute > Stores` there was an error message saying I had to log back in (even though I was already logged in both in AppCenter and appstoreconnect).

Clicking on the "Reconnect" button in the same error message and re-logging in (with the same old credentials) solved the problem.