# Xcode iOS Bundle Identifier

Tags: app-store, verification, bundle-identifier

While archive and validate my app before upload to App Store,error occured:

"No suitable records were found.Verify your bundle identifier "xxx.xxx.xxx" is correct"

But bundle id in project properties, General -> "Bundle Identifier" are the same: "xxx.xxx.xxx". Where may be a problem?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741404/no-suitable-records-were-found-verify-your-bundle-identifier-is-correct

Comment: In my case I had no empty new app in iTunes :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944999/new-itunes-connect-no-suitable-application-records-were-found-verify-your-bun

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278823/xcode-5-no-application-records-were-found-when-trying-to-validate-an-archive