# iTunes Store operation failed. No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier com.SomeLibraryName.SomeName is correct

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, app-store

I’m using **third party framework** in my project. When I’m trying to upload app to AppStore for beta testing with TestFlight I’m getting below error message :

```
iTunes Store operation failed.
No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier com.SomeLibraryName.SomeName is correct.
```

I’m using Xcode 8.2.1 and *trying to upload using Xcode.*

[image: Screenshot 1]

When I switch to *Application Loader* I’m getting `‘Invalid provision profile’` even though the app runs correctly on 
different iPhone device.

I’ve tried below solutions but didn’t worked :

a. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30110914/1753005)

b. [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29741404/1753005)

c. [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29944999/1753005)

Any other fix?

Comment: Are u using Application Loader

Comment: @Maddy : I've checked with Application Loader...it gives 'Invalid Provision Profile' even though it is correct.

Comment: Did you check this http://www.toughdev.com/content/2016/02/error-no-suitable-application-records-were-found-when-submitting-apps-via-xcode/

Comment: @Maddy : Your link was useful...but there might be some way to upload app to AppStore. Question was posted around year back but during this time span developer might have hosted app with third party framework..So there might be some fix.