# No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.Alamofire' is correct

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I have been struggling to get Archive->Validate to work with Alamofire. Only this framework has issues out of all our project decencies.

When I validate my archive to push it to the AppStore, I get following error:
"No suitable application records were found.Verify your bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.Alamofire' is correct".

I have been trying to solve this issue for the 3 past days with no luck. I have followed all suggestions on the internet. Could you please help us to address this issue?

I'm on xCode version 9.0 and pods version 1.3.1

Thank you

Comment: Click on `Alamofire` Pod, What is the bundle identifier here?

Comment: It's a org.cocoapods.Alamofire with 4.5.1 version. All other frameworks have similar names. AWS Core has org.cocoapods.AWSCore. AlamofirImage has org.cocoapods.AlamofireImage

Comment: Did you tried pod install (or) update only Alamofire pod?

Comment: did you solve the problem @Veera?
I am also stuck with it

Answer (score 3):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944999/new-itunes-connect-no-suitable-application-records-were-found-verify-your-bun) for solution.
Basically, iTunes Connect (http://itunesconnect.apple.com) is the receiver of your App bundle when you use the Xcode Uploader utility (in Observer). So unless you have an App with the same bundle identifier created in the iTunes Connect web dashboard, you'll never be able to upload a build. Creating an App on the dashboard is easy, follow these steps from the iTunes home screen:

Create new app if not exist already and submit all required information.
or
Click the app in question. 
Click More ->
Then About This App
Then change the Bundle ID to the one you created in the provisioning portal.

Comment: i can not find Click the app in question .could you point it with picture

Answer (score 2):

Cleaning Build Folder and Derived Data helped me with a similar cocoapod bundle ID issue.

**To clean Build Folder** select Product -> Clean Build Folder in Xcode menu.

**To clean Derived Data:**

1. Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations in the menu
2. Note the path to Derived Data or click an arrow next to it to open in Finder
3. Close Xcode
4. In the Derived Data folder remove the folder starting with your Project name
5. Reopen Xcode and let it reindex the Project

Comment: This worked for my cocoapod bundle id issue as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do a search for your PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER and see what it is. I changed mine to match my application in the App Store Connect.